# Where can I find the standard curves for Bovine Serum Albumin (BSA) and ovalbumin as determined through the Bradford Assay?

Tags: biochemistry, lab-techniques

I was wondering if anyone would please be able to point me in the direction of a database or something similar which contains standard curves/absorbance levels for BSA and ovalbumin, as measured using a spectrophotometer at 595nm, with the Bradford Assay?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Really, you should make your own standard curve, as the concentration of your Bradford reagent may be slightly different than mine, or the one used in a paper, and spectrophotometers can vary significantly. Typically an ampule of BSA or OVA at a defined concentration in PBS is included with Bradford assay kits. This can be serially diluted, then duplicate or triplicate samples added to the same plate as your samples. You can also (very carefully) make standards yourself - just be sure to agitate them long enough so that the protein is completely dissolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Figure 1. Absorbance of Bovine Serum Albumin (BSA) at concentrations of 0, 40, 80, 120, 160, and 200 μg/μl at 595nm.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/285310980_Copper_toxic_stress_on_Aloe_barbadensis_and_its_antioxidant_response)

or

[Figure 2. BSA Standard Curve with absorbance measured at 595 nm, a linear regression was deduced with equation of y = 0.0127x.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/276463041_Study_on_Binding_Affinity_of_a_Glutathione_S_-Transferase_GST_Fusion_Protein_to_DNA_Probe/figures?lo=1)

or

[Steps 7, 15 and 16 here](https://www.protocols.io/view/bradford-protein-assay-protein-concentration-measu-5p3g5qn.html)

or ideally

Please just use a search engine and type in "*bradford protein assay 595nm bsa*" or substitute "*bsa*" for "*ovalbumin*" and see what the world has made available for you in the realms of protein spectrophotometry at 595 nm.

Comment: That’s amazing! Thank you so much!